# NSUserDefaults fail to retrieve image Array

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I try to store array of `UIImage`, it used to work but somehow all of sudden it refused to work. I wrote this test example to check if it's stored properly and I guess the problem is somewhere here

```
let images = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.globalImageArray)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(images, forKey: "morningImages")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
println("Images saved")

let images2 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("morningImages") as? NSData
let imagesArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(images2!) as! NSArray
var testArray = imagesArray as! [UIImage]
println("Check if images are loaded " + "\(testArray.count)")
```

The `testArray.count` is equal to zero which means it either fails to save them properly or fails to retrieve them.

I tried printing images2 and it does contain data, but printing the next value which is imagesArray leads to the result equals to "()" Guess the problem is with this line:

```
let imagesArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(images2!) as! NSArray
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: why not save to disk instead of user defaults

Comment: I find it easier, that's all

Comment: NSUSerdefault is not meant to save things like that, more like primitive data, float , int stringss ...

Comment: I store elsewhere array of dictionaries and it works perfectly fine

Comment: You need to show that `let images = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.globalImageArray)` serializes an array with a count > 0

Comment: I wrote println(self.globalImageArray) above the let images line and it's equal to three

Comment: @DCDC Writing code is not about what is easier. `NSUserDefaults ` is not designed to be a data model store, and certainly not for such massive data as images. Does NSUserDefaults  sound like "array of UIImage"?

Comment: @zaph is right. NSUserDefaults loading is slow (for images), so i'd sugest at least changing to store a list of image paths instead of the data itself. From there, recovering the images from disk is easy.

Still, i would not store them like that (my personal opinion).

Comment: Thanks guys, could I ask you for an example how to store this kind of data in a propr way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this really isn't the best use case for NSUserDefaults. This should be very simple to do by writing to and reading from files on disk.

Here's how I'd do it, and it's less code than saving to NSUserDefaults!

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.globalImageArray, toFile: "/path/to/archive")
println("Images saved")

if let testArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile("/path/to/archive") as? [UIImage] {
    println("Check if images are loaded " + "\(testArray.count)")
} else {
    println("Failed to load images.")
}
```

**EDIT** As it turns out this doesn't work on cached images (e.g. any `UIImage` loaded with either of the `UIImage(named:)` variants because the cached images don't seem to get serialized to disk. So, while the above works for not cached `UIImages`, the following works regardless of the image's cached status.

```
    // Save the raw data of each image
    if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(imageArray.map { UIImagePNGRepresentation($0) }, toFile: archivePath) {
        println("\(imageArray.count) Images saved")
    } else {
        println("failed to save images")
    }

    // Load the raw data
    if let dataArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(archivePath) as? [NSData] {
        // Transform the data items to UIImage items
        let testArray = dataArray.map { UIImage(data: $0)! }
        println("\(testArray.count) images loaded.")
    } else {
        println("Failed to load images.")
    }
```